# ReSharper is suggesting 'Merge Conditional Expression' which will cause a crash

Tags: resharper

So we have the following constructor:

```
public MyDto([CanBeNull] string myValue)
{
    EncodedMyValue = myValue == null ? null : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myValue);
}
```

Where ReSharper is suggesting to merge the conditional expression. However, if I let ReSharper change the code, it changes to this:

```
public MyDto([CanBeNull] string myValue)
{
    EncodedMyValue = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myValue);
}
```

...which ReSharper (correctly) warns is an AssignNullToNotNullAttribute danger.

I can circumvent the problem by adding a `// ReSharper disable once MergeConditionalExpression`, but is there a better approach than just telling ReSharper to shut up and sit down?

I'm using ReSharper version 2019.1.3.

Comment: Have you tried with a R# version that is not three years old?

Comment: @mu88 That would unfortunately require opening a ticket with IT which could take a fair while. I'll do it if necessary, I suppose.

Comment: Which version of .NET and C# are you using? On .NET 7 using R# 2022.3.2, I was not able to reproduce the issue, but it could be related to Nullable Reference Types as well

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2. Okay yeah definitely gonna have to look into upgrading something.